# Can i NOT use an array (just plain old array not an array list) with the base adapter for a list view?

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, listview, baseadapter

I want to use a base adapter for a listview but my data is in a String[]
is this not allowed? cant seem to get the items to inflate in the views... my XML layouts are built correctly.  The java below for the activity in question is posted below.  Im not getting any exceptions, just the list isn't being displayed.

```
public class SuggestedRest extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer clickSound;
    Context context;
    private String[] restaurantSuggestions = {
            "Applebees",
            "Arby's",
            "Baskin Robbins",
            "Ben & Jerry's",
            "Bojangles'",
            "Bonefish Grill",
            "Buffalo Wild Wings",
            "Burger King",
            "Captain D's",
            "Carl's Jr.",
            "Carrabba's",
            "Checkers",
            "Cheeburger Cheeburger",
            "Cheesecake Factory",
            "Chick-Fil-A",
            "Chili's",
            "Church's",
            "Cold Stone Creamery",
            "Cracker Barrel",
            "Dairy Queen",
            "Dave & Buster's",
            "Denny's",
            "Domino's Pizza",
            "Dunkin' Donuts",
            "Five Guys",
            "Hardee's",
            "Hooters",
            "Huddle House",
            "IHOP",
            "Jack in the Box",
            "Jack's",
            "Jason's Deli",
            "Jersey Mike's Subs",
            "Jimmy John's",
            "KFC",
            "Krystal",
            "Little Caesars",
            "Logan's Roadhouse",
            "Lone Star",
            "Long John Silver's",
            "LongHorn Steakhouse",
            "Macaroni Grill",
            "McAlister's Deli",
            "McDonald's",
            "Moe's Southwest Grill",
            "Olive Garden",
            "Outback",
            "P. F. Chang's China Bistro",
            "Panda Express",
            "Panera Bread",
            "Papa John's",
            "Pizza Hut",
            "Popeyes Chicken & Biscuits",
            "Quiznos",
            "Rally's",
            "Red Lobster",
            "Red Robin",
            "Ruby Tuesday",
            "Ruth's Chris Steak House",
            "Sbarro",
            "Schlotzsky's",
            "Shoney's",
            "Smashburger",
            "Sonic",
            "Starbucks",
            "Steak 'n Shake",
            "Subway",
            "Taco Bell",
            "TGI Friday",
            "Waffle House",
            "Wendy's",
            "Whataburger",
            "White Castle",
            "Zaxby's"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.suggested_rest_layout);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        final AdapterSuggestionsList asl = new AdapterSuggestionsList(context, restaurantSuggestions);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_suggested);
        //lv.setAdapter(asl);

    }


    public class AdapterSuggestionsList extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context;
        private final String[] sugArray;

        public AdapterSuggestionsList(Context context, String[] sugArray) {
                    super();
                    this.context = context;
                    this.sugArray = sugArray;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
                    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final ViewHolder holder;

                    if (convertView == null){  // if null then inflate view. if not null then get the view from the stored ViewHolder class object  ("holder")
                        // 
                    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.suggested_row, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    // holder is used as a recycle bin of sorts. once we inflate the view we store it as a holder object and just update the values since inflating is expensive
                        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggested_name);
                        holder.btnAdd= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_sugg_to_fav);

                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                        }  
                    else{
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }

                    // this is the restaurant name
                    holder.name_value = sugArray[position];
                    holder.tv1.setText(holder.name_value);

                    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            clickSound.start();
                            Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddMoreRestaurant.class);
                            intent.putExtra("TAG_THENAME", holder.name_value);  // this tag is opened by the AddMoreRestaurants activity when it is started by this intent
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return sugArray.length;
                }
                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }
                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }
            }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView tv1;
            private Button btnAdd; // the button to add to the favorites
            private String name_value;  // set this to the name of the restaurant and pass it to the intent if needed
        }

}
```

Comment: are you getting any problem with this code...

Comment: why did you commented the `lv.setAdapter(asl);` line...

Comment: @praful, YOU ARE CORRECT THANKS! can you read the comment to Arun's answer? Im really confused about how to implement the commented line in the event that i chose to make this list work inside of a dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the line `lv.setAdapter(asl);`

You need to set the adapter.

Comment: wow i feel dumb... thank you.
question:  the reason i commented this is because it was crashing my app when i was trying to implement this view in a dialog box. any idea how to get this type of view to correctly be in a dialog box?  basically im not sure where to put that commented line when i try to do this same view as a dialog rather than an activity.

Comment: you need to create a custom dialog, inflate the layout containing listview and use the same adapter